# 'int i' is declared as unsigned but the compiler does not give error and gives output as -121 (Range of unsigned int is positive.)

Tags: integer, unsigned

Analyze the following code...
'int i' is declared as unsigned but the compiler does not give error and gives output as -121 (Range of unsigned int is positive.)
Please suggest the reason.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    unsigned int i=-121;
    printf("%d",i);
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the %d is used for signed int values, and now if you want to use it with unsigned value, you cannot use %d as it will display the signed integer value stored at that memory location. Try %u. It should work.

Comment: Thanks man... It worked. Also it is not required to declare the int as 'unsigned'.

Comment: @user1627919 you should declare the variable as the type that you intend to use and be sure to use the correct format specifier in the format string. The reason `printf` doesn't care what you declared it as is because `printf` is not type safe. `printf` assumes the parameter is the type that is indicated by the format specifier and will treat it as such. Some compilers may give you a warning but `printf("%s", i)` will happily assume `i` is a char pointer and crash your program.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, an `unsigned int` cannot be negative (that is what "unsigned" means). If you want to store a negative value in `i`, that line should read `int i=-121;`

See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29#Value_and_representation)